# how send multiple request in soap ui using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, data-driven-tests

I have to run xml request in soap ui with variable.as I understand it is possible with using groovy script. My variable ($variable) should be like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
createResult(34620000+i)
}
```

Request looks like:

```
SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <wq:test>
  <Date xsi:type="xsd:string">2015-01-26</Date>
  <Data ..."$variable"...</Data>
 </wq:test>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Could someone help me to send such request. Or maybe there is another way to send multiple requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:
Define a test case with 3 steps

1. Groovy Script step ==> Name it testCaseControl, you can have below code

```
//run the SOAPRequestStep 5 times, increase as needed
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
   testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('VARIABLE',i.toString()) //set whatever String value required in place of i.toString()
   testRunner.runTestStepByName('SOAPRequestStep')
}
testRunner.runTestStepByName('ExitScript')
```

2. TestRequest step ==> Name it *SOAPRequestStep*, have value as *${#TestCase#VARIABLE}* in place of $variable as you mentioned
3. Groovy Script step ==> Name this as *ExistScript*. This is just used to exit, you may have below code here just to finish the test case.

```
log.info "Running Exit Script"
```

Now run the test case.